# Can not filter my Search results inside my Search Content WebPart based on a Dropdown site columnvalue

Tags: development, search, content-search-web-part, search-query

I have a site column named `Risk/Issue status` which is of type drop down and have multiple values, such as; Open, Closed, In Progress, etc.., as follow:-

[image]

now i want to define a search query inside my Search content web part, to show all the items that have their status != `closed`. so i try the following criteria, but it did not work:-

```
path:"http://servername/sites"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")  EscalatedOWSCHCS:Yes   -Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS:Closed
```

now when i run the query the result will not show any thing..although i have many items which are `In Progress` , `On hold` , etc. so not sure what is wrong in my case?? now if i remove `-Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS:Closed` i will get all the items  , but i am not sure how to exclude the items which have their status = `closed` ??

Comment: Is this really the name of the Managed Property `Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS`? Looks a bit odd with a `/` in it AFAIK

Comment: @RobertLindgren but this is how it is built by defualt ,i actually select it from a list of properties inside my content search web part,i did not write manually.. so not sure what i can do with this?

Comment: Have you tried just getting all the closed items with "Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS=Closed". Note the equals sign rather than a colon which is a contains operator.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott so you are saying that "/" is not the real problem? because when i rename my managed property to be "RiskIssuestatusOWSCHCS" instead of "Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS" my query worked well.. and i am not writing any thing manually so not sure when i need to use "" . i am relying on the query builder windows... where i select the property and click on add...

Comment: No, I am saying you need to test every part of the query. I do suspect that your MP name is part of the issue. Is it working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query usually used in `Content-Search-Web-Part` is called **KQL** (Keyword Query Language).

So there are three things which I want to highlight here :

1. In KQL `:` operator is similar to `equals to` operator whereas for `Not equals to` the operator is `<>`.
2. Try putting `ManagedProperty` or its value in double quotes `"`  if you have characters in Managed Property names like you have `Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS`
3. Try separating multiple conditions with space or additionally wrapped in round brackets`()`

So keeping above mentioned things in mind, your query should be like this.

```
path:"http://servername/sites"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") (EscalatedOWSCHCS:Yes) ("Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS"<>Closed)
```

For more info on KQL, please go through this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx)

Comment: i think my problem is related to having "/" inside the managed property name.. now i rename my managed property to be "RiskIssuestatusOWSCHCS" instead of "Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS" and my query worked well..

Comment: Having "/" is not the problem. Just wrap the Managed Property Name in `"`. I am saying it because I also tried creating exactly same site column as you mentioned and the query worked well with `Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS` as Managed Property Name

Comment: but when i rename it i got the correct results,, it is really confusing.

Comment: Have you to tried using `"Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS"` instead of using `Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS` ?? Because of "/" character in ManagedPropertyName, your query wasn't considering `Risk/IssuestatusOWSCHCS` as complete Property Name. So we have to specify it in double quotes. Renaming managed property to simple text is always going to work.